# changeset with deleted files only

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

from my changeset history, I able to see complete set of changeset.

[image: list of changeset: 11971, 11972, 11973]

but when I try to retrieve the list programmatically, it didn't return my 11972 changeset.

[image: missing 11972 changeset]

changeset 11972 only contain all the deleted files.

[image: 11972 changeset content]

```
IEnumerable changesets = versionControlServer.QueryHistory(
   "$/PROJECT_NAME",
   LatestVersionSpec.Instance,
   0,
   RecursionType.Full,
   null,
   new ChangesetVersionSpec(1),
   new WorkspaceVersionSpec(workspace),
   10,
   false,
   false);
```

Kindly please help...
thanks.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested on my side with the code snippet below, it could return all changesets as expected. You can try to replace `new WorkspaceVersionSpec(workspace)` to `VersionSpec.Latest`, and check whether changeset 11972 is under path `$/PROJECT_NAME`:

```
IEnumerable changesets = VCServer.QueryHistory(
            "$/PROJECT_NAME",
            LatestVersionSpec.Instance,
            0,
            RecursionType.Full,
            null,
            new ChangesetVersionSpec(1),
            VersionSpec.Latest,
            10,
            false,
            false);
```

You can also use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get%20changesets?view=vsts-rest-5.0) to get the changesets:

```
Get https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$top=10&searchCriteria.itemPath=$/PROJECT_NAME&api-version=5.0-preview.3
```